# How to trigger azure pipeline in one topic branch during push for another topic branch

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My azure devops pipileine's yaml file is not in master branch of bitbucket. Its in another branch inside master branch (master/pipeline-branch). I am trying to trigger that build when there is a push to another topic branch which is also not the master branch. (master/topic/secondary).

In my yaml file I have written the trigger like this.

trigger:
- topic/secondary

But no build is triggered when I push a file to secondary branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cherry pick\merge commits with this file to the secondary branch or just commit the yaml file to the secondary branch. when a commit is made a decision to start the build or not is being made by evaluating the yaml file inside the branch a commit was made to. if the file doesnt exist in that branch - there is nothing to trigger