# How do I trigger a pipeline to start from a branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

As a follow up to my previous question [How do I set up different pipelines for each branch in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211005/how-do-i-set-up-different-pipelines-for-each-branch-in-azure)

I want to trigger the build based on a different branch so if I build the branch `virt/master` on a project `multi-branch` using the pipeline `multi-branch (virt)` I am setting up my `deploy-virt` pipeline as

```yaml
trigger:
- master

resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: virt
     project: experiments
     source: multi-branch (virt)
     trigger:
      branches:
        - virt/master
```

However, making a change on the `virt/master` branch which runs the `multi-branch (virt)` pipeline does no trigger my `deploy-virt` pipeline.

Same sort of question, am I missing something [hopefully obvious] or am I facing a bug in Azure DevOps Pipelines.

Closest but not quite duplicate [How to trigger azure pipeline in one topic branch during push for another topic branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968711/how-to-trigger-azure-pipeline-in-one-topic-branch-during-push-for-another-topic) because that one is looking at a repo push rather than a pipeline execution.

[deploy-virt](https://dev.azure.com/trajano/experiments/_apps/hub/ms.vss-build-web.ci-designer-hub?pipelineId=13&branch=master) pipeline code.

Answer (score 0):

OK it's something obvious

```yaml
trigger:
- master

resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: virt
     project: experiments
     source: multi-branch (virt)
     branch: virt/master # this one
     trigger:
      branches:
        - virt/master
```

The documentation wasn't really clear on this (emphasis mine)

> branch: string  # branch to pick the artifact, **optional**; *defaults to all branches; Used only for manual or scheduled triggers*

But adding it seems to make it work considering this wasn't a manual/scheduled.